# Как идентифицировать пользователей одновременно в Java и php?

Tags: php, java

Пользователь нажимает в java-проекте кнопку, открывается браузер с ссылкой, он куда-то там нажимает и в итоге открывает php-скрипт, которому передаются данные о том, что и как он там нажимал.
В базе данных должно храниться следующее: уникальный идентификатор (что-то типо ip, mac, но обязательно уникальное!) и эти данные.
Как добиться того, чтобы, кликнув на кнопку в Java, Java начала бы обращаться к БД с неким уникальным идентификатором каждую секунду, а в php сохранился бы тот же самый идентификатор вместе с данными. Вопрос даже не в том, как добиться этого, а в том, какой идентификатор использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос про то, какой идентификатор использовать, то можете генерировать уникальный токен (передавать его пользователю в cookies), который может выдаваться при авторизации (либо сразу после первого посещения сайта). Но лучше комбинированный подход - uid и token (когда по uid осуществляется быстрый поиск по базе, в token используется в качестве пароля).